# Updating library configuration to work with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

We have an application library that we want to update to work with both ASP.NET Core and previous versions of ASP.NET.  This library currently depends on the ConfigurationManager class to read settings from Web.config.  With the changes to the configuration in ASP.NET core, is there a suggested way to create a library that can read the configuration from both an ASP.NET Core web application and a pre-ASP.NET core web application?

Example of current logic for reading the configuration settings.

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace Test.MyLibrary
{
    public class MyLibrarySettings : ConfigurationSection
    {

        private static MyLibrarySettings settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyLibrarySettings") as MyLibrarySettings;

        public static MyLibrarySettings Settings
        {
            get
            {
                return settings;
            }
        }

        public string SomeSettingValue
        {
            get { return (string)this["someSettingValue"]; }
            set { this["someSettingValue"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET Core you can directly use instance of [IConfiguration](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions/IConfiguration.cs), that 
represents a set of key/value application configuration properties:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a configuration value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The configuration key.</param>
    /// <returns>The configuration value.</returns>
    string this[string key] { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

so you can write code like

```
    private IConfiguration _configuration;

    public string SomeSettingValue
    {
        get { return (string)_configuration["someSettingValue"]; }
        set { _configuration["someSettingValue"] = value; }
    }
```

Keep in mind, that ConfigurationBuilder.Build() method returns `IConfigurationRoot`, that is inherited from `IConfiguration`:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents the root of an <see cref="IConfiguration"/> hierarchy.
/// </summary>
public interface IConfigurationRoot : IConfiguration
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am still not clear if there is a way for this library to read the configuration settings regardless of whether the web application using it is using ASP.NET core or pre-ASP.NET core.  The IConfiguation interface is new to ASP.NET core from what I can tell so wouldn't work with a pre-ASP.NET Core application.  Probably tells me I have my configuration setup incorrectly.